# Brake Noise at low speed while slowing in damp conditions

Tags: brakes

Have a 2017 grand cherokee about 30k miles. While slowing off the highway to a stop, no problems. Smooth as silk. After slow driving for a little bit, when slowing from 10 to 0, I get a thump thump thump, mainly after I press harder, harder, harder but not slamming the brakes on.

Now, it sounds to me like a deep sounding squeak as if the pads are grabbing and sticking to the rotors, then when they let go I hear the squeak. It feels and sounds like when you have a wet finger and slide it across a balloon. It grabs the balloon then squeaks when it slides across it.

Dealer replaced the rotors and said the pads were fine. I went in again and it was a beautiful dry day and I couldn't get it to re-occur. After the recent snow, it is happening a lot. The dealer where I bought it will fix for free but it is very inconvenient to get there from my home or office.

I can do things on my own but don't know what to do. Maybe replace the pads?

Any thoughts what might cause this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you ever replace the rotors but not the pads? Used pads always have some grooves in them, so contact to disc will not be even until setting in. This is dangerous, and pads are so cheap and come out when swapping the rotors anyways!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like partially glazed pads - as Daniel mentioned in a comment pads should generally be replaced along with discs anyway but in this case it sounds like it *really* should have been done.

I'd suggest doing this ASAP - the sticking/grabbing your feeling could result in uneven wear on the discs if left too long.

Comment: I thought something was up with the pad, just didn't know what. Pads it is! I can report back if that is the solution. Thank you for your help!!